# My button I created progmatically to push from my app the Apple Maps app stopped working.. why?

Tags: ios, swift, button, mapkit

I have a navigation app I am working on which works like a normal maps app, allowing you to search for locations through a search table etc.  So in my app I have a button which allows for the user to add multiple annotations (be default every time the user clicks a new result in the searchtable I have it set to remove the most recent annotation) and find the centerpoint between all these areas.  The code then shifts that centerpoint to the closest address so there is a place to get directions to, not just lat and long.  Anyway, I have it set so that when the user taps the annotation, a button appears right above it, and the button is supposed to send you to apple maps with the preset route already loaded in.  This worked until recently. Here is the code that carries this button's actions out:

```
extension ViewController : MKMapViewDelegate {
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView?{
    if annotation is MKUserLocation {
        //return nil so map view draws "blue dot" for standard user location
        return nil
    }
    let reuseId = "pin"
    var pinView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: reuseId) as? MKPinAnnotationView
    pinView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)
    pinView?.pinTintColor = UIColor.red
    pinView?.canShowCallout = true
    let smallSquare = CGSize(width: 30, height: 30)
    let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(origin: (CGPoint()), size: smallSquare))
    button.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "car"), for: [])
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(getDirections), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)

    pinView?.leftCalloutAccessoryView = button
    return pinView
}
}
```

and in the class

```
@objc func getDirections(){
    if let selectedPin = selectedPin {
        let mapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: selectedPin)
        let launchOptions = [MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey : MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving]
        mapItem.openInMaps(launchOptions: launchOptions)
    }
}
```

Could it be something weird with the objective C function?  This is the code I recently added that potentially could have caused the issue, though I really don't know:

```
func resolveAddress(for averageCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D, completion: @escaping (MKPlacemark?) -> () ) {

    let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
    let averageLocation = CLLocation(latitude: averageCoordinate.latitude, longitude: averageCoordinate.longitude)
    geocoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(averageLocation) { (placemarks, error) in
        guard error == nil,
            let placemark = placemarks?.first
        else {
            completion(nil)
            return
        }
        completion(MKPlacemark(placemark: placemark ))
    }
}

@IBAction func middleFinderButton(_ sender: Any) {

    let totalLatitude = mapView.annotations.reduce(0) { $0 + $1.coordinate.latitude }

    let totalLongitude = mapView.annotations.reduce(0) { $0 + $1.coordinate.longitude }

    let averageLatitude = totalLatitude/Double(mapView.annotations.count)

    let averageLongitude = totalLongitude/Double(mapView.annotations.count)

    let centerPoint = MKPointAnnotation()

    centerPoint.coordinate.latitude = averageLatitude
    centerPoint.coordinate.longitude = averageLongitude


    mapView.addAnnotation(centerPoint)

    resolveAddress(for: centerPoint.coordinate) { placemark in
        if let placemark = placemark {
            self.mapView.addAnnotation(placemark)
        } else {
            self.mapView.addAnnotation(centerPoint)
        }
    }

    print(totalLatitude)
    print(totalLongitude)
    print(averageLatitude)
    print(averageLongitude)
    print(centerPoint.coordinate)

    }


}
```

Anyone have an idea why this button isn't working and pushing the app to maps with a preset route? could it be a glitch with the simulator(it used to work so I doubt it)?  Thanks.

Comment: Do you see the button on the screen? Is there a reason you're programmatically declaring the elements of your view rather than laying it out in your view controller?

Comment: @Adrian I'm not exactly sure how to make this type of button normally rather than programmatically.  Here's the Github link: https://github.com/derekvandermark/VHNavigationAppOfficial-v-0.93